# How can i draw a graph with multiple edges on a single vertex (e.g. allowing loops)?

Tags: java, graph, edges, jgraphx

I'm using JGraphX to draw a graph. I need to draw a graph with multiple edges (joining two vertices) and create a loop on the vertex. Is it possible in JGraphX?
For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mxGraph.setAllowLoops(boolean value)`](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/java/docs/com/mxgraph/view/mxGraph.html#setAllowLoops-boolean-) method to enable looping. Loops are disabled by default.